# Asynchronus DMA mem2mem copy doesn't transfer data

Tags: c, linux, driver, beagleboneblack, dma

I'm working on a device driver that needs to preform mem to mem copies via dma on a Beaglebone Black (ARM) with Linux Kernel 5.4.106. So far I've managed to successfully request a mem to mem compatible channel (and release it when I'm done), but I'm unable to perform the actual transfer.

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/dmaengine.h>

struct dma_chan *chan;
void *src;
void *dst;

static int __init mod_init(void)
{
    dma_cap_mask_t mask;
    int ret;
    struct dma_async_tx_descriptor *tx = NULL;
    dma_cookie_t cookie;
    int *writer;
    enum dma_status status;
    printk("mod_init called\n");

    dma_cap_zero(mask);
    dma_cap_set(DMA_MEMCPY, mask);

    chan = dma_request_channel(mask, NULL, NULL);
    if(!chan){
        printk("no mem2mem channels available");
        ret = -EAGAIN;
        goto fail_chan;
    }
    printk("requested channel");

    src = kzalloc(16,GFP_KERNEL);
    if(src == NULL){
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto fail_m1;
    }
        dst = kzalloc(16,GFP_KERNEL);
    if(dst == NULL){
        ret = -ENOMEM;
        goto fail_m2;
    }
    writer = (int *)src;
    *writer = 20;

    tx = chan->device->device_prep_dma_memcpy(chan, virt_to_phys(dst), virt_to_phys(src), 16, DMA_CTRL_ACK | DMA_PREP_INTERRUPT);
    if (!tx) {
        printk("prep error");
    }
    printk("slave configured");
    cookie = tx->tx_submit(tx);

    if (dma_submit_error(cookie)) {
        printk("submit error");
    }

    dma_async_issue_pending(chan);
    status = dma_async_is_tx_complete(chan, cookie, NULL, NULL);
    if(status != DMA_COMPLETE){
        printk("something went wrong");
    }
    printk("dst: %d, src: %d", *(int *)dst, *(int *)src);

    printk("done");
    return 0;
fail_m2:
    kfree(src);
fail_m1:
    dma_release_channel(chan);
fail_chan:
    return ret;
}

static void __exit mod_exit(void)
{
    printk("mod_exit called\n");
    dma_release_channel(chan);
    printk("dst: %d, src: %d", *(int *)dst, *(int *)src);
    kfree(src);
    kfree(dst);
    printk("released channel");
}

module_init( mod_init );
module_exit( mod_exit );

MODULE_AUTHOR("Me");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("DMA engine test.");
```

This kernel module compiles without any issues and when installed does not cause any errors. Eventho the cookie returns a DMA_COMPLETE status, the value in `dst` stays 0 (it should become 20).
Most of the code is based on the [dmatest](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/5.4/drivers/dma/dmatest.c) driver, which preforms flawlessly, but my copy is missing the mark.

What could be the issue here? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding GFP_DMA flag to your kzalloc() calls - the memory you allocate should be suitable for DMA transfers, that is platform-dependent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried it, but sadly no effect. To my knowledge my platform already puts memory allocated with Kernel flag in a DMA'able region. In addition to that the [driver](https://github.com/beagleboard/linux/blob/5.4/drivers/dma/dmatest.c) that I'm taking inspiration from also only uses the kernel flag and it works there.